# How to import react element without immediately rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import a simple clock react component (from the react tutorials) in another react project, and it is rendering upon import, even if I don't use the tag. How is this happening, and how can I prevent it?

Clock repo:
https://github.com/bobtista/reactJsClock

Tic Tac Toe repo (where I want to show the clock):
https://github.com/bobtista/reactJsTickTacToe/tree/feature/clock

If I try to use a named export, the Clock shows up as undefined in jsconsole. To reproduce:
In clock repo:

```
module.exports = Clock;
```

In tic tac toe repo:

```
import { Clock } from "my-clock";
```

If I use default export, I get this error

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in

And I noticed that if I don't even use the  tag, when debugging, before the  can load, the Clock renders to the window - simply by being imported it shows up.

To reproduce:

```
export default class Clock extends React.Component {
```

and
    import Clock from 'my-clock';

FYI: It works here! How?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eteavk?file=index.js

Comment: when you import XYZ from '...' you usually get the Component without rendering. Can you show some code?

Comment: I added the repos and reproduction steps. I have tried removing the ReactDOM.render part of the clock entirely, as even when I was only importing the Clock class, the ReactDOM.render function was running. I tested this by changing div id from "root" to "root2" and the clock, just by being imported, was erroring out that it couldn't find "root"

Comment: I've noticed that if I don't use webpack in the clock repo and point package.json to bundle.js (the output of webpack), the import won't work. Is that supposed to be the case? Seems odd that react can't import react and needs webpack to de-reactify it